# Cargar Formulario de Windows Forms en un panel 2 veces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, windows-forms, .net

Buen día, tengo un programa el cual tiene dos paneles (Uno para el menú y el otro para mostrar lo que clickeaste del menú), el problema es que uno de los botones en específico no funciona 2 veces, es decir si haces click en el, te manda el form al panel correctamente pero si haces click en otro botón (te arroja el respectivo menú) y regresas a dar click al botón para abrir el primer panel, no funciona.
Únicamente pasa con ese botón, no con ningún otro, es la siguiente porción de código la que utilizo para abrir el form dentro del panel:

```
 private void BtnCandidatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormCandidato Frm = new FormCandidato();
        Frm.TopLevel = false;
        PanelChildForm.Controls.Add(Frm);
        Frm.Show();
    }

    private void BtnAsignacionR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AsignacionReportes Frm = new AsignacionReportes();
        Frm.TopLevel = false;
        PanelChildForm.Controls.Add(Frm);
        Frm.Show();
    }

    private void BtnBuscarCandidato_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormBuscarUsuario Frm = new FormBuscarUsuario();
        Frm.TopLevel = false;
        PanelChildForm.Controls.Add(Frm);
        Frm.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Saludos. (años que no programo aplicaciones de escritorio); busca en cada `Form` su correspondiente evento donde se cierra y agrega código para removerlo del `PanelChildForm.Controls`; asimismo el `TopLevel` que pones indica que no se ponga encima de algún formulario desde donde se invoque (si lo invocas debieras mostrarlo por encima de donde lo invocas ¿o no?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
 private void BtnAsignacionR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormEnPanel(new AsignacionReportes());
    }

    private void BtnBuscarCandidato_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormEnPanel(new FormBuscarUsuario());
    }

    //Función para abrir un Form en el Panel central directo desde el menú izquierdo
    private void AbrirFormEnPanel(object formhija)
    {
        if (this.PanelChildForm.Controls.Count > 0)
            this.PanelChildForm.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        Form fh = formhija as Form;
        fh.TopLevel = false;
        fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.PanelChildForm.Controls.Add(fh);
        this.PanelChildForm.Tag = fh;
        fh.Show();

    }
```